# Android - keep webservice results in memory

Tags: android, rest, memory

In my Android app I have to query some user/session dependent data from a rest webservice. Now I need a way to keep the received webservice results in memory, so that serveral activities/fragments can access them. 
I don't want to persist the data (for example a list of the users bank accounts) into a database on the device, because the data expires after a while or when the user logs out. 
I also don't want to request the data again and again from webservice, when the user navigates to another activity.

Are there any approved patterns to keep a set of data (some pojo's with more or less properties) in memory during the application is running?

Just for info: I'm experimenting with dagger2, mvp, retrofit2, rxandroid

Regards
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already experimenting with Dagger 2, then all you need to do is instantiate a component in `Application` and use this component in your `Activities` and `Fragments` in order to inject a scoped "service".

For example:

- Create a class named `XyzManager` (where Xyz = the actual functionality this manager is responsible for)
- Annotate its `@Provides` method (in Dagger's module) with `@Singleton` scope
- Make sure that the component that injects `XyzManager` instantiated in `Application` and add `getComponent()` method to your custom `Appliaction` class
- In your `Activities` and `Fragments` inject `XyzManager` while using the same component - `((MyApplication)getApplication()).getComponent().inject(this)`

  If you take the above steps, then all your `Activities` and `Fragments` will get a reference to exactly the same instance of `XyzManager`, and the data you cache in this manager will be accessible everywhere.

  The structure you would get is very similar to the structure described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40200805/2463035).

Please note that this approach is much better than resolving to `static` things (e.g. Singleton pattern, or what @KhalidTaha suggested in his answer).

You might want to take a look [at my post](http://www.techyourchance.com/dagger-2-scopes-demystified/) concerning Dagger 2 scopes if you need a detailed information on that aspect of the framework.

Comment: Hi! thanks for your answer!
I thought about something similar, but I'm afraid I don't catch on dagger2 completely :)

Comment: ... Let's say I have a "SessionServiceImpl" wich I want to be a singleton. And i want to use constructor injection for this class. How do i structure my other components to get a single instance of SessionServiceImpl?

Comment: @maschin, I linked to another answer to a similar question which has almost all the required code in it. Also, there are a lot of tutorials out there.

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution:
1- create a DefaultUtil class:

```
public calss DefaultUtil{

    private List<User> listOfUsers;
    public static DefaultUtil getInstance(){
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = new DefaultUtil();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    public List<User> getUserList(){ return listOfUsers; }
    public void setUserList(List<User> userList) {

        this.listOfUsers = userList ; 
    }

}
```

2- when you finish the webservice, call this code:

```
DefaultUtil.getInstance().setUserList(myWebserviceListOfUsersResult);
```

and then you can access the list of users from any class by this:

```
DefaultUtil.getInstance().getUserList();
```

Comment: While this approach might work, I would argue that it is not an "approved pattern", but an anti-pattern that should be avoided.

Comment: you can also make an object of the DefaultUtil and make the List non-static attribute, and create a Singlton constructor for the class, see the edit

Comment: While making use of Singleton pattern makes this approach a "more standardized", I would still argue that this is an anti-pattern. See my answer for an alternative way of doing this without resolving to `static`s

Comment: the two solutions are true, my solution is easier to implement, but your solution is more perfect pattern

Comment: thanks for your answer Khalid Taha, but I think I prefer the dagger-way

Answer (score 0):

@Vasiliy
I've studied the linked answer, but I don't get it. I don't use my BankingSession singleton in an activity directly, so calling "getComponent().inject(this).... " won't work. I use the singleton in other service classes (not Android services... just business logic).

```
// this should be a single instance across the whole app
@Singleton
public class BankingSession { 

    @Inject
    public BankingSession() {
    }
}


public class SessionServiceImpl implements SessionService {

    private final BankingSession bankingSession;

    @Inject
    public SessionServiceImpl(BankingSession bankingSession) {
        this.bankingSession = bankingSession;
    }
}


@Module
public class SessionModule {

    @Provides
    public SessionService provideSessionService(SessionServiceImpl sessionService) {
        return sessionService;
    }
}


@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, NetworkModule.class,    SessionModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {
    Application application();
    LoginComponent plus(LoginModule module);
    AccountComponent plus(AccountModule module);
    BankingSession bankingSession();
}
```

No matter how I try it, the constructor of BankingSession get's called multiple times

Comment: sorry, i figured out that anywhere else in my code i had a "new  BankingSession()", so I thought dagger2 isn't handling the singleton correctly.